# Redirect to mobile site as soon as mobile device id detected

Tags: mobile

I have my main website running on IIS, JAVA and i have my latest mobile website running on apache, php. I want to redirect use to mobile website as soon as mobile is detected. Can i do something in IIS or need to write some code in my main website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try HandsetDetection.com. The service detects mobile and tablet browsers and helps you redirect to the most optimized version of your page. It's also free for up to 20k detections per month!